# react-custom-scrollbars package working example typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

I want to use the react-custom-scrollbars package in a typescript react project but I can't make it work. I am looking for a working example as the examples mentioned in the GitHub repo aren't working in a typescript react project.

Answer (score 0):

https://gitlab.com/damjan89/i18next-typescript-example Here you can find implementation of react-custom-scrollbars in typescript